# Pass. talent PT4 VLS exact meaning

Tags: visas, france

I applied for a "Passport Talent" visa for France. I got the visa and came to France but am confused about the meaning of it. I tried to validate my visa online but was unable to do so.
My duration in France will be 3 years.

The information written on the visa is:

```
Valid for: France
From: 25-12-22
Until: 25-03-23
Duration of stay: XXX
Type of visa: D
Number of entries: Mult
Remarks: Pass. Talent; Chercheur; PT4 VLS
```

Confusion 1: I need to validate my Visa online? or need to apply for the residence permit?

Confusion 2: what is meaning of PT4 VLS?

Comment: VLS-TS means “visa de long séjour valant titre de séjour”. In theory you get a VLS-TS if the duration of stay is under a year, and then you need to validate it (and the visa alone is enough, no need for a residence permit). For stays over a year, you get a temporary 3 months visa, and then you need to go to the Prefecture to get your longer residence permit (titre de séjour).

Comment: My visa comment is PT4 VLS.

Comment: What does it mean by PT4 VLS?

Comment: Unfortunately, depending on your location in France, getting an appointment to the préfecture might be a challenge. https://administration-etrangers-en-france.interieur.gouv.fr/particuliers/#/espace-personnel/connexion-inscription

Answer (score 3):

You have a VLS (long stay visa), and not a VLS-T*S* (long stay, valid as a residence permit)

You need to ask for your residence permit at your local *Préfecture* before the visa expires

From @jcaron

> VLS-TS means “visa de long séjour valant titre de séjour”. In theory you get a VLS-TS if the duration of stay is under a year, and then you need to validate it (and the visa alone is enough, no need for a residence permit). For stays over a year, you get a temporary 3 months visa, and then you need to go to the Prefecture to get your longer residence permit (titre de séjour).

Comment: Now, the system is online. I need to apply online for the residence permit?

Comment: @zuhaibhassan I wasn't aware of that, then yes, you need to apply online

Comment: (+1) To be clear, you always need to apply for a *carte de séjour* before the end of the visa, even with a VLS-TS. The difference is that this visa is only valid for three months, like most long-stay visas originally were. A VLS-TS would be valid for a year.

Comment: @Relaxed You can't apply for a *carte de séjour* if you're staying for 1 year or less (because VLS-TS are issued for those stays). A *carte de séjour* is only available to VLS-TS holders if they wish to extend their stays above the validity of the visa. The goal of VLS-TSs is to relieve some stress off of the *carte de séjour* system, you just need to validate the visa online,.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella I don't disagree with this but you can always apply for a *carte de séjour* as long as what you have is a *visa long séjour*, whatever the kind. And, yes, a *carte de séjour* is only available to those who wish and have a reason to extend their stay beyond the validity of their visa but that's equally true of a regular *visa long séjour*.

Comment: For once, the rule is relatively easy: Outside of limited exceptions (e.g. *vie privée et familiale*), you need a *visa long séjour* to be allowed to apply for a *carte de séjour* and you need to do that before the expiration of your visa. That's really all the OP needs to keep in mind. Once that's clear, we can get into all the niceties around the VLS-TS, new online procedures, etc. but understanding these simple rules should resolve their confusion around what they need to do now that their visa is about to expire because the same is true in all cases.